# ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID for Google-managed SSL on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I successfully set up a custom domain for my website on Google App Engine, and SSL security is listed as "Google-managed, auto-renewing". I've tested my domain on multiple SSL checker sites without any problems being reported. But when I visit the site with https://, I an ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error page is displayed. Also, the certificate says that it was issued to "p4-preview.runhosting.com" which I've never heard of and produces a 404 error when visiting it. Why isn't SSL working on my site and where did runhosting come from?

Comment: I suggest you post this on Serverfault, as you may have more help there. This is not, strictly speaking, a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know the cause of the issue, but some time after I posted the question SSL began working properly. I didn't make any changes that should have affected this, so my only guess is that I just needed to wait longer for things to update.

Comment: I seem to get this error when I deploy a new version and the cert is issues to gvt3.com